# CodeIgniter: Регулярное выражение для мультиязычного сайта

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, codeigniter

Помогите составить регулярное выражение на мультиязычный сайт.

Поле проверки на имя пользователей

```
/* Пример доступных символов в имени (вариантов много, я урезал)

username
имя пользователя
Emri i përdoruesit
імя карыстальніка
korisničko ime
nom d'usuari
ຊື່ຜູ້ໃຊ້
Korisničko ime
სახელი
נאמען
Uživatelské jméno
Όνομα χρήστη
lietotājvārds
Användarnamn
օգտագործողի անունը
ユーザー名
用户名
ឈ្មោះ​អ្នកប្រើប្រាស់
प्रयोगकर्ता नाम
பயனர்பெயர்
ชื่อผู้ใช้
کا صارف کا نام
اسم المستخدم
שם משתמש
kullanıcı adı
*/

// Здесь описываем правила
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Имя', 'required|min_length[1]|max_length[64]');

if($this->form_validation->run()){
    $name = $this->input->post('name');
    $this->login_model->insert($name);
}
```

В CodeIgniter есть параметр для этого `regex_match[/match/]`, вот только как составить данную регулярку ума не приложу.

Варианты типа `regex_match[/[a-z]+/i]` как видно не подходят, и даже экранирующая последовательность `\w` не вариант.

Подскажите как коротко и правильно составить `regex_match[/match/]` ?

Comment: Каковы требования к шаблону?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, не пропускать если есть спецсимволы которые не должны быть, проблема в том что точно и не опишешь какие символы запрещать, под запрет явно идут (№#\/*+&?$;:[]{}()@!%^ и другие)

Comment: В общем, когда определитесь, добавьте в текст вопроса. Без этого дать точный ответ невозможно.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, требование к шаблону самые простые, описал в вопросе в самом начале, проверка на доступные символы в имени на разных языках, если регулярка соответствует то TRUE, иначе FALSE, буду рад за любую помощь или в направлении куда копать

Comment: Имена, говорите. Под запрет явно идут "(№#\/*+&?$;:[]{}()@!%^" говорите... [Не все так просто](https://habr.com/post/146901/)